# like and dislike in reat Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I used `material-ui` card and in this kind of card, there is a like button so I fetch data from the server and show them on cards everything is great until now I just click the like button to add one of them to my favorite part but all of them selected.

this is my card that is fetched from server :

```
<React.Fragment>
  {advert && advert.map((info, i) =>
    <Grid item xs={4} key={i}>
      <Card className={classes.root} >
        <CardHeader
          title={info.title}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Title: {info.title}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing >

          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites" onClick={() => like(info.id)}>
            {likee ? <FavoriteIconLike /> : <FavoriteIconDislike />}
          </IconButton>

        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  )}
</React.Fragment>
```

and i write like function like this:

```
const [likee, setLikee] = React.useState(false)
const like = (id) => {

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('user', sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
  formData.append('code', id);

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${SERVER_URL}/src/api/like.php`,
    data: formData,
    responseType: 'json',
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log(response)
      if (response.data === 'insert') {
        //like discount
        setLikee(true)
      } else if (response.data === 'delete') {
        //dislike
        setLikee(false)
      }

      return response;
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      //handle error
      console.log(response)

    })
}
```

when I click one of the like buttons in card ,the card that I clicked save in the database correctly but in cards, every like button changed not only the one I clicked.

I take some shots of my cards. the first one is when the like button did not click.

[the like button does not click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2GKN.png)

the second shot is when I click one of them but all of them changed.

[when one of the like buttons clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZctNi.png)

and the adver comes from databse ans is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "34",
        "user": "jk.k.kk@gmail.com",
        "price": "78",
        "text": "But when it comes to other components, you may not want to repeat the width and height. In these instances, you can pass children and it will infer its width and height from them. But when it comes to other components, you may not want to repeat the width and height. In these instances, you can pass children and it will infer its width and height from them. But when it comes to other components, you may not want to repeat the width and height. In these instances, you can pass children and it will infer its width and height from them.",
        "url": "..\/public\/uploadPic\/4318b4e04db99f70a9c12cd87b845b641.jpg",
        "token": "fw1kcgkwiwvkerds4faeub13ovli1eis",
        "title": "hall of city",
        "start": "2020-10-03T14:32",
        "expire": "2020-10-29T14:32",
        "code": "erftgyhujk",
        "time": "2020-10-27 16:43:24"
    },
    {
        "id": "32",
        "user": "tytytytyt@gmail.com",
        "price": "45",
        "text": "The data for your components might not be immediately available. You can increase the perceived performance for users by using skeletons. It feels like things are happening immediately, then the information is incrementally displayed on the screen (Cf. Avoid The Spinner).\n\nThe component is designed to be used directly in your components. For instance:",
        "url": "..\/public\/uploadPic\/dd6f5eb18ea833fa1a7aa55f3de097e72.jpg",
        "token": "fw1kcgkwiwvkerds4faeub13ovli1eis",
        "title": "super market",
        "start": "2020-10-05T14:30",
        "expire": "2020-10-29T14:30",
        "code": "rfghnmjkoo",
        "time": "2020-10-27 16:43:35"
    },
    {
        "id": "33",
        "user": "rtrtyhhjhj@gmail.com",
        "price": "67",
        "text": "In addition to accepting width and height props, the component can also infer the dimensions.\n\nIt works well when it comes to typography as its height is set using em units.In addition to accepting width and height props, the component can also infer the dimensions.\n\nIt works well when it comes to typography as its height is set using em units.",
        "url": "..\/public\/uploadPic\/51074e4633a745ac50e3b9943c7970636.jpg",
        "token": "fw1kcgkwiwvkerds4faeub13ovli1eis",
        "title": "AcademyAgri",
        "start": "2020-10-30T14:32",
        "expire": "2020-10-31T14:32",
        "code": "rtbawscbnj",
        "time": "2020-10-27 16:43:39"
    },
    {
        "id": "35",
        "user": "ytytytytyt@gmail.com",
        "price": "45",
        "text": "The icon prop allows you to add an icon to the beginning of the alert component. This will override the default icon for the specified severity.\n\nYou can change the default severity to icon mapping with the `iconMapping` prop. This can be defined globally using theme customization.\n\nSetting the icon prop to false will remove the icon altogether.",
        "url": "..\/public\/uploadPic\/86936421c73e575abbd3ad39a27da1c31.jpg",
        "token": "fw1kcgkwiwvkerds4faeub13ovli1eis",
        "title": "fffflady",
        "start": "2020-10-13T14:22",
        "expire": "2020-10-31T14:22",
        "code": "ujk,powedf",
        "time": "2020-10-27 16:43:47"
    },
    {
        "id": "36",
        "user": "sfsefseefs@gmail.com",
        "price": "90",
        "text": "By default, the skeleton pulsate, but you can change the animation for a wave or disable it entirely.\n\nBy default, the skeleton pulsate, but you can change the animation for a wave or disable it entirely.\n\nBy default, the skeleton pulsate, but you can change the animation for a wave or disable it entirely.\n\nBy default, the skeleton pulsate, but you can change the animation for a wave or disable it entirely.",
        "url": "..\/public\/uploadPic\/f2277a2b2272b8386f266077962340939.jpg",
        "token": "fw1kcgkwiwvkerds4faeub13ovli1eis",
        "title": "sexy fgfg",
        "start": "2020-10-30T16:34",
        "expire": "2020-10-31T16:34",
        "code": "hfE45DAsQf",
        "time": "2020-10-27 16:35:06"
    }
]
```

Comment: in `setLikee` i didnt see that you pass index of liked element. it will be way better if you provede working example

Comment: how can pass index in setLikee??

Comment: You have to track each record status in the state. Your state should be array of id and status

Comment: when i click every like button the id code that is in like function pass correctly and save in database but all of like button changed

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell because you haven't actually shown the entirety of the related code (how is advert defined? Where are you rendering the card?) but based on your code, it seems like you're rendering the card for each element of an array of adverts.

If this is the case, and the component rendering that fragment is the same component with the `likee` state, the issue is simple: the component rendering every card stores only one `likee` value being applied to every card. That means that every card's `likee` value will be dictated by the `likee` value of a single card, whichever one modifies that of the parent component.

If `advert` contains an array of adverts, each one rendering a card, then consider abstracting that card into a separate component that can contain its own state. That way you can have a separate `like` state for each card, storing whether or not it has been liked.

That component might look like this:

```
const AdvertCard = ({ info }) => {
  const [advertLiked, setAdvertLiked] = useState(false); // Has this advert been liked?
  
  const like =  (id) => {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('user', sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    formData.append('code', id);
              
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url : `${SERVER_URL}/src/api/like.php`,
      data : formData,
      responseType: 'json',
      config : {headers : { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
    })
      .then(function(response){
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data === 'insert') {
          //like discount
          setAdvertLiked(true);
        } else if(response.data === 'delete') {
          //dislike
          setAdvertLiked(false);
        }
  
        return response;
      })
      .catch(function(response){
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
      })
  }

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root} >
      <CardHeader
        title={info.title}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
          Title: {info.title}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing >

        <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites"onClick={() => like(info.id)}>
          {advertLiked ? <FavoriteIconLike/> : <FavoriteIconDislike />}
        </IconButton>

      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

With the component rendering every advert returning the following:

```
<React.Fragment>
  {advert && advert.map((info, i) => 
    <Grid item xs={4} key={i}>
      <AdvertCard info={info} />
    </Grid>
  )}
</React.Fragment>
```

Also, please use clearer variable names than `likee`. Having a state a `likee` state and a `like` function makes it unclear which variable/function should be used in which scenarios and how each one should specifically behave differently from the other.